# How to send a message and collect reactions from it in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If a bot was to send a message

```
            vote_msg = await ctx.channel.send('Vote ' + '@' + str(member) + ' out of the server? **' + str(out) + '/' + str(of) + '**')
            await vote_msg.add_reaction('✅')
            await vote_msg.add_reaction('❎')
```

How could I get the bot to add up the reactions after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `message.reactions`: [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions)

```py
            vote_msg = await ctx.channel.send('Vote ' + '@' + str(member) + ' out of the server? **' + str(out) + '/' + str(of) + '**')
            await vote_msg.add_reaction('✅')
            await vote_msg.add_reaction('❎')
            await asyncio.sleep(30) # wait 30 seconds with the asyncio module (import asyncio if you haven't already)
            vote_msg = await vote_msg.channel.fetch_message(vote_msg.id) # refetch message
            # default values
            positive = 0
            negative = 0
            for reaction in vote_msg.reactions:
                if reaction.emoji == '✅':
                    positive = reaction.count - 1 # compensate for the bot adding the first reaction
                if reaction.emoji == '❎':
                    negative = reaction.count - 1

            print(f'Vote Result: {positive} positive and {negative} negative reactions')
```

Comment: I get `Vote Result: 0 positive and 0 negative reactions` even though the reaction isn't 0.

Comment: @ZacIsa Oh I see, what I forgot is that you have to refetch the message! Should be fixed now