# How to send long fields as pages in embed discord.py?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord, discord.py

for example this code here, it's working but with some names for example https://api.ashcon.app/mojang/v2/user/TonTon70
is too long and gives this error 'Must be 1024 or fewer in length'
so i saw some bots sending long fields as pages with left and right arrow

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json
from tabulate import tabulate

@client.command()
async def namehistory(ctx,*username):
    async with ctx.typing():
        embed = discord.Embed(
        discription = "discription",
        color = discord.Color.green()
        )
        if not username:
            embed.add_field(name="Name History", value="Username not supplied!", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

    nurl = "https://api.ashcon.app/mojang/v2/user/" + username[0]
    nr = requests.get(url=nurl)
    data = nr.json()

    if "username" in data and data.get("username") != 'null':
        nhistory = data['username_history']
        nhistory = tabulate(nhistory,headers="keys")
        embed.add_field(name="Name History", value=f"```{nhistory}```", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Wrong username!")
````

Comment: Embed fields natively have a 1024 character limit (you can find the limits somewhere in https://discord.com/developers/docs). You should try splitting them up into multiple fields or sending multiple messages

Answer (score 0):

The "pages" in an embed are really just separate embeds with [message reaction collectors](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions). Message reaction collectors are events that fire when a user reacts to a message. To learn how to use message reaction collectors, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841280/how-to-send-a-message-and-collect-reactions-from-it-in-discord-py):

```py
embed_message = msg.channel.send(your_embed)     # send the first page embed

embed_user = msg.author                          # get the msg user

await embed_message.add_reaction("⬅️")           # send the page back button
await embed_message.add_reaction("➡️")            # send the page next button

await asyncio.sleep(30)                          # user has 30 seconds to react to a msg, you can change the timings. Also don't forget to import asyncio

embed_message = await embed_message.channel.fetch_message(vote_msg.id) # after waiting 30 seconds, get the reactions for the msg
```

Now, the reaction information is in `embed_message`. You can use an `if` statement to read what reaction was chosen. Also, don't forget to check that the reaction was actually from the correct user by comparing it with `embed_user`. If you need help with that, feel free to check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction)

```py
for reaction in embed_message: # embed_message returns a list
    if reaction.users().flatten()[embed_message.index(reaction)] == embed_user: # test if the correct user reacted before performing checks
        if reaction.emoji == "⬅️":
            # code to send the previous page embed...
        elif reaction.emoji == "➡️":
            # code to send the next page embed...
```

Good luck with your bot!